# Spring LDAP search with organisational units returns zero results

Tags: active-directory, spring-ldap, ldap-query, ou

I'm working on a plain java command line software which performs a recursive LDAP search with Spring LDAP, starting from a specified group and searching all the users from the specified groups and subgroups.

The search fails to find anything if the group distinguished name contains organisational units (=ou), but works in other cases.

Here is the short version of implementation, recursion omitted:

```
private void searchLdapGroup(List<UserDTO> users, LdapTemplate ldapTemplate, String groupName) {
    // recursion guard omitted
    String base = groupName.substring(groupName.indexOf(',') + 1);
    AndFilter filter = new AndFilter().and(new EqualsFilter("objectclass", "group")).and(new EqualsFilter("memberof", groupName));
    List<String> subgroups = ldapTemplate.search(base, filter.encode(), new GroupNameMapper());

    // recursive calls for subgroups omitted
    getAllUsers(users, ldapTemplate, groupName, base);
}

private void getAllUsers(List<UserDTO> users, LdapTemplate ldapTemplate, String groupName, String base) {
    AndFilter filter = new AndFilter().and(new EqualsFilter("objectclass", "person")).and(new EqualsFilter("memberof", groupName));
    // Paged search omitted.
    List<UserDTO> result = ldapTemplate.search(base,filter.encode(),new UserAttributesMapper());
    users.addAll(result);       
}
```

The `GroupNameMapper` returns distinguishedName as Strings and `UserAttributesMapper` returns user objects from different attributes such as `sAMAccountName` and `givenName`.

The code (with recursion) finds all the 36 users in the first test group, where the specified group is like:

> CN=import_users,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=test,DC=org

in the same exact test environment it returns zero persons and subgroups when the group distinguished name contains one or more organisational units, such as

> CN=import_users,**OU=testou**,DC=example,DC=test,DC=org

This can't be due to wrong group distinguished name, "memberof" not working or group containing no users, since i tested lookup:

```
String[] test = (String[])ldapTemplate.lookup("CN=import_users,OU=testou,DC=example,DC=test,DC=org", new ContextMapper() {
        public Object mapFromContext(Object ctx) {
            DirContextAdapter adapter = (DirContextAdapter) ctx;
            return adapter.getStringAttributes("Member");
        }
 });
```

which finds

> CN=John Doe,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=test,DC=org

and lookup for the user John Doe

```
String[] test = (String[])ldapTemplate.lookup("CN=John Doe,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=test,DC=org", new ContextMapper() {
        public Object mapFromContext(Object ctx) {
            DirContextAdapter adapter = (DirContextAdapter) ctx;
            return adapter.getStringAttributes("memberof");
        }
    });
```

gives results:

> CN=import_users,OU=testou,DC=example,DC=test,DC=org
>   CN=import_users,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=test,DC=org

How come the search does not find anything when organisational units are involved?

Library user: 
**spring-ldap-core - 2.0.4.RELEASE**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The devil is in the details:
The member of the group `CN=import_users,OU=testou,DC=example,DC=test,DC=org` is

> CN=John Doe,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=test,DC=org

But you appear to be searching for users under

> OU=testou,DC=example,DC=test,DC=org

That is, it appears all users are under `CN=Users,DC=example,DC=test,DC=org`, but when you are actually searching for users you assume they are placed relative to the group.

Comment: Yes, this seems to bee at least a partial answer - the users and groups appear to be in `CN=Users,DC=example,DC=test,DC=org` - which is why the recursion also worked, since the subgroup also has dn like `CN=subgroup,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=test,DC=org`. The ad-tree and traversing it is different from what i thought...but this should work for other ad systems as well, so now i got a bunch of new problems and probably have to scrap the current traversing method.

Comment: Since you have the complete DN for the user from the group member attribute, you could simply `lookup()` that DN to find the user.

Comment: Yes, that was the old way to do it: looking up possibly thousands of users and multiple groups one by one works, but is slow - and this user fetching is supposed to work eg. once every night. I tried a new solution, cropping the base to be only `DC=example,DC=test,DC=org` and searching sub tree scope for groups/users with the exact same filters as before - seems to work at least in the test environment cases.

Comment: That should probably work, but you need to be aware of server limits in that case: it's quite common for AD servers to limit the number of elements returned by an LDAP search to a relatively low number (e.g. 1000). If a search returns more than this limit it will throw an exception (unless you use paging, which is completely hopeless in LDAP). Your server administrator should be able to provide you with information on whether such a limit is in effect.